# FullCalendar with multiple Users

Tags: javascript, ruby, mongodb, fullcalendar

We currently use an Excel spreadsheet to display the schedules of our 5 member management team. It's a pretty easy thing to do as we only have three shifts: D = day shift, E for evening, and M for midnight. Cell comments show any specific activities on a particular shift.

The time has come to move away from Excel into a more dynamic environment and I'd like to use FullCalendar along with my MongoDB and some Ruby scripting. However, not being a JS expert, I want to know if it is possible to view all 5 schedules on one calendar? Perhaps a checkbox next to each managers name that will display their calendar if checked, or all managers if all checked type of environment.

I did not see this type of functionality on the docs, so the next best place to find out is to ask the experts here!

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes it is possible!!you can use scheduler of fullcalendar and show these users schedule all at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]First you'd need scheduler add-on of fullcalendar and you are good to go.
Heres an example

```
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                            schedulerLicenseKey: 'your key here',
                            header: {left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: ''},
                            selectable: true,
                            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                            ignoreTimezone: true,
                            allDayDefault: false,
                            unselectAuto: false,
                            editable: false,
                            slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
                            events: [   //the events example
            [
                id: 1,
                type: null,
                resourceIds: [
                    21
                ],
                title:"Meeting With John",
                start: 2017-02-13 09:00:00,
                end: 2017-02-13 11:20:00,
            ],
            [
                id: 2,
                type: null,
                resourceIds: [
                    22
                ],
                title: "Appointment With Doctor",
                start: 2017-02-13 10: 00: 00,
                end: 2017-02-13 13: 20: 00,
            ],
        ],

     resources: [ // these resources examples are the users you want to create(where its id is mapped to resourceIds in events JSON )
            [
                id: 21,
                title: "User A"
            ],
            [
                id: 22,
                title: "User B"
            ]
           ]

                        });


<div id="calendar" style="width:100% !important">

</div>
```

See the snapshot for the example.
Let me know how it works out ...

Comment: That looks exactly like what I want!! I'll let you know when I have it finished!

Comment: @user2843365 sure thing!! Glad to help!!